# Alternative to .ToList() to return HUGE quantity of data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I've got a query that returns more than 212Milion rows. I tried to use `.ToList()` but it obviously goes in `OutOfMemoryException`. What is the best alternative for my case?

I tried also to use  `Skip(fetchedrows).Take(1000).ToList()` but performance really slow down on skipping phase and query never end.

Comment: Can you filter the query prior to getting 212 million rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq Can split into the sublists work for you?

Comment: If you really have to change 212 millions data, consider making an SQL stored procedure that does it instead, it can't be faster than SQL

Comment: @AntoinePelletier It depends on what you are doing. Some actions just aren't possible from stored procedures, but generally that is a good option indeed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, Oper you should tell us what kind of manipulations you are doing, you take these lines to accomplish something, what is it?

Comment: Actually, i don't do anything with this data, This is for a project of performance comparison between SQL Server and MongoDB. In MongoDb i can do this query in 8 hours storing the results in another colleciton. But in SQL Server i don't know how to retrieve this data without going in MemoryException.
I'm also thinking about insert this rows in a new table, but i don't know a way to do that (going from var x = (linqtosql statement) to db.QueryResult.AddRange(x);

Comment: You are testing the limits... you reached it ! Seriously, consider Patrick's answer or... admit there are limitations to what a computer can do... good luck with your furtur tests.

Comment: Why don't you use a smaller data set? You don't need these large amounts to reveal performance differences. Also, how useful is the comparison? SQL- and NoSQL databases serve different goals. It's a bit like comparing a Landrover to a Lamborgini. Depends on the landscape who wins.

Comment: Dataset is not so big, this is the result of a query, not the size of the dataset.

Comment: Whatever. Why 212 million? One million will suffice to demonstrate that MongoDb will easily beat SS in tasks it's geared to doing fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, return an enumerable. That way you can keep on scrolling forward (and forward only) through the excessive amounts of rows without the need of placing it in memory at once, which will most likely never work. If implemented correctly (it also depends on your data source), you can read and process one row at a time, with virtually no memory in use.

There are many techniques to do this, but the easiest way I often use is `yield return`, which will generate its own state machine.

Entity Framework nowadays does stream the results itself. The only thing you should *not* do is call `ToList()` or similar methods which would load all rows from the database in memory. Just iterate over the results as if they were regular collection. (For EF6 and older you can use the [`AsStreaming()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237204.aspx) extension method.) If that doesn't work for you, you can always revert to a `DataReader` where you read and return row by row.

Comment: It doesn't work pretty good because when we use yield, we will trigger a request to the database getting the same amount data to the memory.

Comment: No, using `DataReader` you just read one row at a time. The data provider you use might send more rows at once, but often you can control that too. @EdneyBatistadaSilva

Comment: @PatrickHofman But he's *not* using a `DataReader`, he's using EF.

Comment: As you said, the datareader do that, but in this case yield statement forces the EF compile and trigger the query to make the IEnumerable to return on the instruction, in the same way, it brings all the rows.

Comment: @Servy That is what I said. Updated to use EntityFramework's `AsStreaming()` which does about the same.

Comment: AsStreaming() extension method is obsolete. Am i missing something? how can i use this from linqtosql? Can you be more precise?

Comment: I see, that was EF6. The current version is streaming by default, so if you don't call `ToList()` on it, it will not retrieve all data at once.

Comment: is it possible with this method see how mutch time query execution take? Even if the results are not taken all in one?